# Tail-call optimization is not applied?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, tail-recursion

I get a stack overflow error in VS C++ 2010 while traversing a search tree with the following two functions, mutually calling each other:

```
Node* Node::GetNextNodeStartHere(const Node& treeroot, NodeCondition condition)
{
  if ( condition( *this ) )
  {
    return this;
  }

  return GetNextNode(treeroot, condition);
}

Node* Node::GetNextNode(const Node& treeroot, NodeCondition condition)
{
  if ( HasChildren() )
  {
    return GetChild(0).GetNextNodeStartHere(treeroot, condition);
  }

  Node* pnextnodetosearchfrom = BacktrackToNotLast(treeroot);

  if ( pnextnodetosearchfrom == NULL )
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  return pnextnodetosearchfrom->GetNextNodeStartHere(treeroot, condition);
}
```

I assumed that this mutual recursion is subject to the tail-call optimization as `return` statement is always the last in the code flow. Was I mistaken?

I use `O2` switch for a build and run the Release build from the command line.

EDIT:

Thanks for the comments from @arcadyg and @hdv, I changed the signature for the functions as follows:

```
Node* Node::GetNextNodeStartHere(const Node& treeroot, NodeCondition& condition)
Node* Node::GetNextNode(const Node& treeroot, NodeCondition& condition)
```

where

```
typedef std::function< qbool (const Node&) > NodeCondition;
```

After the change, all calls of `GetNextNodeStartHere(...)` are optimized out. However, `GetNextNode(...)` still gives a stack overflow. My current suspect is pointer `pnextnodetosearchfrom`, although it seems strange. Isn't the compiler smart enough to handle this?

Comment: Don't rely on tail-call recursion to prevent stack overflow in C++. It's just not guaranteed.

Comment: By definition the return is always last in the code flow, so I think you misunderstood something. Maybe it means there is only one return?

Comment: @NeilKirk It's not always last in the code flow: think of destructors of objects with automatic storage duration. That said, it is here, and the return expression is a function call without any operation being applied to its result, not even any implicit conversion, so tail recursion is possible here.

Comment: So, does `NodeCondition`, in fact, have constructors and destructors?

Comment: I had posted a general answer about why some compilers might simply not bother with this optimisation at all, but according to [this blog post](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/visual-c-code-gen-deficiencies/), Visual Studio 2010 is supposed to be capable of tail call optimisation, so now I'm curious why it might not be happening for you.

Comment: @anatolyg: it's a lambda, more precisely ``std::function< qbool (const Node&) >``

Comment: @AdelNick Those are two different types. I spoke too soon when I said there is nothing happening after the `return`. A lambda expression's compiler-generated type may have a trivial destructor, but `std::function<T>` does not and cannot, because `std::function<T>` has to work even when the wrapped function object has a non-trivial destructor.